# How can I forward SMS to Another Using the Echo Twimlet

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I just need to forward whatever incoming SMS to my mobile phone. I would prefer to just use a Twimlet like Echo but what I've tried so far doesn't work.

https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/echo

Ex:

Where  should be or be replaced with whatever keyword is used for the body of the incoming text.

Comment: Given that echo just emits TwiML, you'd do it [the same way you'd normally forward an SMS](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-do-i-forward-my-sms-messages-to-another-phone-number).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately I'm not sure there is a way to do this by using Twimlets since we don't have one that knows how to grab the body of the inbound message and use it generate the TwiML needed to send a new outbound message.

Its a good idea though and I've passed it to the team that owns Twimlets.

If you don't want to run your own server, then you could look at using a service like Parse (which has a free tier and an [integrated Twilio SDK](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Twilio.html)) to stand up a simple endpoint that takes the inbound message body and then asks Twilio to send a new outbound message with that body.

devin

Comment: Thanks for tip, Devin! I wrote a little app which does exactly that on parse if someone needs it - https://github.com/dabido/TwilioSmsRedirect

Comment: Good news, now Twilio supports templates, read in this article How-To https://twilioinc.wpengine.com/2016/10/introducing-templates-for-twiml-bins.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this now.

`http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=<Response><Message>Hello there!<%2FMessage><%2FResponse>`

This twimlet was built for voice, but I have tested it with SMS and it works.

Comment: How would you actually forward the inbound message using the echo twimlet? It is passed in the body of the request or as a url parameter.